# For a line $L$ and an algebraic curve $C$ of an irreducible polynomial, prove $C \cap L$ contains at most d points unless C = L.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves

Artin Algebra Chapter 11

[image]

This has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241714/the-intersection-of-algebraic-curves). My questions are about the solution of [Brian Bi](http://brianbi.ca/artin/11.9):

[image]

1. By stronger, does he mean that $C \ne L$ *and* $f$ is irreducible $\implies l \nmid f?$ If so, here is my proof. Is it correct?

Since $f$ is irreducible, $l$ divides $f$ if and only if $\frac f l =: k$ is a nonzero constant. Then

$$C=\{f=0\}=\{kl=0\}=\{l=0\}=L$$

2. Is $a=0=b$ ruled out by definition of linear?

If so, is this in book, or is it understood because $a=0=b$ gives either $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb C^2$? If not, how do we prove $|C \cap L| \le d$ in the case where $c=0$? I was able to show just $C \cap L = C$.

3. Why is it that $g$ has degree $\le d$?

I think this has something to do with:

- irreducibility of $f$ and
- what it means for $d$ to be the [degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3056563/198044) of $f$.

I think of writing $f=e_0(y)+e_1(y)x^1 + ... + e_m(y)x^m$. If each monomial has degree $\le d$, then because $y=px+q$ has degree 1, $g$ has degree $\le d$, being made up of monomials in one variable that have degree $\le d$. Therefore,

- it's irrelevant that $f$ is irreducible, and
- the definition that $d$ is the degree of $f$ is that all its monomials have degree $\le d$, and one of them has degree $d$?

Comment: If f is not irreducible, then it might happen that L is a component of C (i.e. L is a factor of f), without being all of C. In this case there are infinitely many points in the intersection. This is the stronger thing. L divides f does not jmply that C is L. The third equality is wrong - kl = 0 holds if l is zero OR k is zero (a union of sets).    Yes $a = b = 0$ is ruled out in order for it to be a line (one dimensional affine subspace). The degree of f is in terms of monomials like $x^ay^b$, which has degree $a + b$.

Comment: @Lorenzo 1. I am thinking. 2. Thank you! 3. So we know the degree of the monomials that make up $f$. Then what's the degree of $f$? Highest of the degrees?

Comment: @Lorenzo For 1, $k$ is a nonzero constant because $f$ is irreducible, correct?

Comment: @Lorenzo Also for 1, my understanding was that the exercise asks us to show $f$ is irreducible and $C \ne L \implies |C \cap L| \le d$ and what Brian Bi tries to show is that $f$ is irreducible and $l \nmid f \implies |C \cap L| \le d$. Do you mean it's actually that Brian Bi is showing that $l \nmid f \implies |C \cap L| \le d$ and therefore the "stronger" is that "$C \ne L$ *and* $f$ is irreducible$ \implies l \nmid f?$" I think so, so I'll edit that now.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible (and of degree $> 1$), then there is no $k$ so that $f= kl$. If $f$ is irreducible and we write $f = kl$, then $k$ or $l$ is a constant. Yes the degree of $f$ is the highest of the degrees. Probably reading a book like Fultons' algebraic curves  will help clarify this stuff: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf